# How do I get an Expression out of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Please, how do I extract an expression from a string?
For example, I have this string below:

RECEIPT_NO=5001809252729&**PAYMENT_CODE=500858991537884262034**&MERCHANT_CODE=0350000AFT&TRANS_AMOUNT=42990.0&TRANS_DATE=2018/09/25 14:04:28&TRANS_DESCR=Victor-300%20Level%20-001-

What I want to do is compare the value inputted by a user with the value in bold 
How do I go about it using PHP?

I had tried using `str_split('/[&]/', $string);`, but I wasnt getting what I wanted. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a string in standard HTTP "query string" format (percent-encoded and `&`-separated key=value pairs). The easiest way to handle it is using PHP's built-in [parse_str()](https://secure.php.net/parse_str) function:

```
$items = [];
parse_str($string, $items);
echo $items["PAYMENT_CODE"];
```

If this function did not exist, you could reimplement it;

```
$items = [];
foreach (explode("&", $string) as $item) {
    list($key, $val) = explode("=", $item, 2);
    $items[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `explode()` in PHP;
In your case like this :

```
$str = 'RECEIPT_NO=5001809252729&PAYMENT_CODE=500858991537884262034&MERCHANT_CODE=0350000AFT&TRANS_AMOUNT=42990.0&TRANS_DATE=2018/09/25 14:04:28&TRANS_DESCR=Victor-300%20Level%20-001-';

$arrayOfVars = explode('&',$str);
```

[look at explode() documentation in PHP.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)